SharePoint Online: Access Denied for Site owner with full control
In a SharePoint online site, site owner with full control on the site is getting Access denied error when tried to access site permissions settings or click on page permissions though they have permissions with full control on the site owner group.
If i add them to site collection admin, they have access. But can't provide that permission.
Any solution/ideas?
Thanks
Ganesh

check permission levels - ensure the default "Full Control" set of permissions still includes all itemized permissions

Please kindly provide more information below to let us work further.
1.Are other users with permissions facing the same problem? View through another computer or account.
2.Check if the same issue occurs with other SharePoint site collections. You could create a new SharePoint site to check.
3.You could try to clear browser cache then restart it.
4.Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same error occurs.
